# Cell border in xtragrid

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have one Devexpress xtragrid with certain columns. Now I want to remove the bottom and left borders of the second and third column. Is there any way to achieve this?  I tried to draw cell border with the grid back color. But it seems not working for me.

I have attached the screen shot of the grid with in which I have marked the expected behaviour. Kindly help me.

[image]

Comment: Does the [cell merging](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1461) feature suits your needs?

Comment: It will not work, problem is two columns are bounded and I guess I need to additional processing if I merge it.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [How to merge cells horizontally in GridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2472) example which demonstrates how to implement a similar feature.